# What is the thinking behind OS X and iOS modifying my settings across updates?

Tags: macos, updates, ios, default-settings

Every time I update OS X, the **Guest account** is turned on. Every time I update iOS, **bluetooth** is turned on. I always have to manually turn these settings back off after updating. Why does Apple not respect these settings? Can anyone point me to some information online which might explain this?

Comment: can't comment on iOS, as I always have bluetooth on, but my Mac guest account remains off after updates. I'd investigate permissions, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuration management is difficult with large scale deployments like those you describe.

Often, new features add new configuration options, change the way configuration settings are used, and what sets of options should be used together or not. The relationship between settings can be complicated, and not all those relationships are visible to the developer at design time.

Additionally, iOS upgrades are more akin to a firmware/ROM flash than they are to a traditional install like you would see with Windows or non-embedded linux updates, where a program is run which coordinates and controls the application of each step in the upgrade. That leaves few opportunities for iOs to change the way the update is applied to your system.

Apple has made the choice to implement a default "known safe state" for all configuration options, and has decided to reset them on each install. It is notable that both windows and Linux distros have a history of issues with upgrade operations that are not present with a clean install. They've both gotten better over the years, but the unpredictable state of a users customized device often presents difficulties to the upgrade routine.

I would probably not make this choice, but I do think their choice is consistent with the way they like their ecosystem to run: that it just works with no tweaking or adjustments.

Ultimately, there is no way to know what happens in the design meetings, but that answer is sufficiently satisfying for me.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I understand the compromises you describe. It would be very helpful to be given a log showing any settings that are changed or no longer available post-update. A `diff` for settings, basically.